What peace is needed in high places?
The Kaddish concludes as follows:

עוֹשה שָׁלוֹם בִּמְרומָיו הוּא יַעֲשה שָׁלום עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשרָאֵל וְאִמְרוּ אָמֵן


May He who makes peace in His high places give peace to us, and to all Israel, and let us say "Amen".

Why does peace need to be made in God's high places?  Is there dissension in heaven?  What kind?  (Order is not peace.)

It's a straight quote from Bildad (Job 25:2). See commentaries to that verse for various explanations.

@Sholom That's rashi's second answer. See too https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.23b.14

"Is there dissension in heaven?" No, proving He has indeed made peace.

@DoubleAA -- Proves also that there was not peace "before".
